# How to properly format "systems as diverse as X and Y"?

Tags: word-choice, writing-style

I'd like to express that a certain framework is very versatile and can model a wide array of phenomena. What I have so far is

> This setup is extremely general, and allows for modeling systems as diverse as X and Y

Where X and Y are examples of two very different systems. 
 Is this OK? It sounds a bit off to me. If not, how do I properly format this sentence?

Also, I'm not sure what the appropriate tags are for this question, please feel free to edit them.

Comment: X and Y aren't real diverse.  If for X you substitute "the Federal Reserve System's complex procedure for evaluating and predicting the threats against the dollar in global markets", and something even more complex for Y, then you might want to consider reformatting.

Comment: You could say “...modelling everything from [X] to [Y]”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Diverse* certainly carries the sense you require here:

> **diverse** adjective ... B2  ...
>
> ​[b] very different from each other:
>
> *We hold very diverse views on the topic.*

[[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/diverse), adjusted]

The complication here is that the default sense of 'diverse' speaks of variation **within** a composite unit:

> B2 [a] including many different types of people or things: ...
>
> *New York is a very culturally/ethnically diverse city.* ...
>
> *Linguistics embraces a diverse range of subjects such as phonetics and stylistics.*
>
> *There is a diverse range of opinion on the issue.*
>
> *India is quite diverse, both politically and religiously.*
>
> *Members of the largest and most diverse phylum of animals (Arthropoda), have segmented bodies and an external skeleton.*

So, to avoid this ambiguity which possibly defaults to the unintended sense (X is diverse and Y is also diverse) (although context would lead the informed reader to suspect the intended reading), one could use

> This setup is extremely general, and allows for modeling systems as
>   different / disparate [stronger] as X and Y.